# Internal network security policy for development environment

Tags: network, defense

What are the best practices for network security for an internal development environment. Besides adhering to updates, antivirus, and firewall.

For instance, is it recommended to use an IDS/IPS like Snort? Should you be whitelisting outgoing ports? Developers often needs access to a variety of resources, especially for testing purposes.

What kind of security controls are often overlooked in these type of environments?

I know this is a very broad question, so any and all answers are appreciated.

EDIT: The network is an internet connected LAN.

Comment: Is a stand-alone network?  Or connected to the Internet somehow?

Comment: It is connected to the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, follow a iSMS such as ISO 27002, PCI DSS, Visible Ops Security, or similar.

Overlooked controls include [2FA](https://twofactorauth.org) authentication and TLS protection of developer repos (e.g., GitLab, Subversion, Atlassian, Perforce, et al) that conform to [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com) criteria, as well as other components of Application Lifecycle Management (ALM), such as tools for bugtracking, code documentation, code review, collaboration, et al. API keys are always at risk: developers accidentally leave these in their code, .git/.svn folders, etc. Be aware, have backups, and have a backup plan when all else fails.

... And remember, the best penetration testers in the world attack developers, not apps -- http://www.darkreading.com/attacks-breaches/tiger-team-member-attacks-developers-not-apps/d/d-id/1129737